# How can I use a single Horizon instance to monitor jobs from all sites on server

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-horizon

I have multiple (Laravel 5.8) sites on a single Laravel Forge server.

Instead of installing Horizon on all sites I would rather have a single site running just Horizon with some basic authentication.

All sites are using the same Redis instance running on the server.

I would like to monitor all jobs created on all sites via this single Horizon dashboard, however I can't seem to get Horizon to see the jobs created by the other sites.

The jobs are running as expected, but not showing in Horizon.

- I have tried removing the `HORIZON_PREFIX` env value in the Horizon config but that doesn't work.
- I have tried setting `HORIZON_PREFIX` on the Horizon site, and `REDIS_PREFIX` on the other sites to the same value but that doesn't work either.

Note: The other sites are not running Horizon at all (something I want to avoid), they are just communicating with Redis in the standard way.

What am I missing?

Comment: Horizon is started directly from the codebase of one project. I don't think you can run jobs of other projects with a different codebase through the same instance. Having a global dashboard could be possible though (with some tweaks).